# Hexadecimal from number over serial port

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, networkstream, hex

Hey all i am trying to control the master volume on my Onkyo Receiver. Problem being is that it works until i get to volume 10. **Volume numbers 0-9 work just fine** (raises volume from 0 to 9). However, when i go to volume 10 it displays the volume as being **16**. **Volume 11=17**, **Volume 12=18**, etc etc.

The excel sheet says this:

```
"00"-"64"   Volume Level 0 - 100 ( In hexadecimal representation)
```

[image]

And the serial command is:

```
Public Function remoteCommands(ByVal theCommand As String) As Boolean
    Dim Stream As NetworkStream
    Dim Client As New TcpClient()
    Dim streamw As StreamWriter
    Dim i As Int32
    On Error GoTo blah

    Client.Connect(main.avIP, 60128)
    Stream = Client.GetStream()
    Dim returndata As String = ""

    If Client.Connected And Stream.CanWrite Then
        streamw = New StreamWriter(Stream)
        Dim sendBytes(theCommand.Length + 18) As Char

        sendBytes(0) = "I"
        sendBytes(1) = "S"
        sendBytes(2) = "C"
        sendBytes(3) = "P"
        sendBytes(4) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(5) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(6) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(7) = Chr(16)
        sendBytes(8) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(9) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(10) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(11) = Chr(theCommand.Length + 3)
        sendBytes(12) = Chr(1)
        sendBytes(13) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(14) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(15) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(16) = "!"
        sendBytes(17) = "1"

        For i = 0 To (theCommand.Length - 1)
            sendBytes(18 + i) = theCommand.Chars(i)
        Next

        sendBytes(theCommand.Length + 18) = Chr(13) '&HD
        streamw.Write(sendBytes)

        Dim bytes(Client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        Stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(Client.ReceiveBufferSize))
        returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

        streamw.Flush()
    Else
        MsgBox("error: Stream.Canwrite failed")
    End If
    Client.Close()
End Function
```

And this is how i call the function above:

```
Dim vol As String = Trim(lanSent(1).Replace("AVVOL", ""))

If Len(vol) = 1 Then
   vol = "0" + vol
Else
   Select Case vol
      Case 10
        vol = "a"
      Case 11
        vol = "b"
   End Select
End If

Call avReceiver.remoteCommands("MVL" & vol)
```

I was looking for converters and i noticed that **10** represented **A** in Hexadecimal. But even sending that **MVLA** doesn't do anything.

What would i be missing?

**UPDATE (and solved)**

```
Dim vol As Integer = Trim(lanSent(1).Replace("AVVOL", ""))
Dim vol2 = vol.ToString("X2")

Call avReceiver.remoteCommands("MVL" & vol2)
```

[image]

Comment: Please **use the debugger as I asked**. Set a breakpoint on the `stream.Write` line, and when the breakpoint is triggered look at the contents of `sendBytes`. Look at the **actual content** that is being sent to the receiver.

Comment: @KenWhite i would have used the debugger but its calling a web service to do this. Although i did whip up a short VB of what it would be sending the the WS and it came out as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send `OA` (zero A). The text says it's looking for hex `00` to hex `64` (decimal 0 to 100). Note that the hex values are expressed as two digits, not one.

If you're actually using VB.NET as your tag indicates, you're doing it wrong. :-) You should be using something like:

```
newvol = 10;
vol = newvol.ToString("X2")    `Converts to 2-digit hex string
Call avReceiver.remoteCommands("MVL" & vol)
```

Comment: Still seems that when i send **10** it still says its **16** on the receiver?

Comment: Then you've edited something wrong. :-) My code would send it `MVL0A`, which is `MVL` + 10 decimal (`0A` hex). If your receiver is showing `16`, you're not sending it `10` somehow. Put in some `MessageBox` or other ways to examine the array you're sending (or use the debugger to view it by setting a breakpoint) and look at the actual characters in the array. I've answered your question about properly sending the hex values; I can't see what your code is actually sending it, because I don't have all of your code or the receiver here. If it's showing `16`, you have to be actually sending `10`.

Comment: 0a does show **16** but it should show **10** on the receiver and **not 16** because thats what i need it to show, **10**...

Comment: `0A` is `10 decimal`. If it's showing `16` on the display, you're sending it `10` **hex** instead. Please read what I wrote - use the debugger to actually see what you're sending it. **We can't see it from here**.

Comment: I rolled back your edit above. That's *not* the way SO works; you can't move the target as we're trying to answer.

Comment: Got it working. Had it as string when it needed to be converted as an integer! Thanks for the help, Ken! :o)